# Do browsers (specifically portable browsers) have fingerprints, meaning can be distinguished from other installs or portable save?

Tags: firefox, usb, browser

Do browsers (specifically portable browsers) have fingerprints, meaning can be distinguished from other installs or portable save?

Example:
If I used the portable browser saved inside my USB stick on searching a specific site, then I transfer location and use again that same portable browser inside my USB stick, can it be trace that it comes from the one same 'Portable Browser Install' regardless of the new i.p. address?

Comment: What specifically is your concern....are you doing something that somebody might not like if you are discovered?  Hopefully your question concerns ethical and lawful behavior.

Comment: A good IT admin has ways to identify portable applications.  I find it odd there have been a ton ( at least six ) questions about portable browsers in the last 48 hours.

Comment: You should check Panopticlick. My mobile Chrome is complaining about SSL, so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Actually the url is https://panopticlick.eff.org

Answer (score 0):

As for fingerprints, you're browser name and version are always available to any of the sites.  So if you have a specific/special browser you are using you could be identified.  Also if you leave cookies on your USB that could be used to track your whereabouts.

A final note, anytime you login into anything on the web you'll leave discernible trace information.

I'm sure that if enough time and energy is put into the efforts you might be identified by any searches or type of unique behavior you are generating on the network despite which browser you use anyway.